# I need to know number of encryption/decryption operations?

Tags: des

If i want to break quadruple DES (say EDED), what is complexity? Like for EDE, it is O(2^112).

Comment: How many keys??

Comment: Hint, assuming 4DES with independent keys: minimally adapt a simple technique that works with 3DES, leaving the part dealing with the first two rounds unchanged. $\;$ For the best theoretical complexity of breaking 3DES with independent keys, see Stefan Lucks: _Attacking Triple Encryption_ [in proceedings of FSE 1998](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-69710-1_16), which has it less than $2^{112}$ DES operations. $\;$ Notice that strictly speaking, $O(2^{112})$ is the same as $O(1)$, and thus best avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the purpose of EDE. EDE only specifies the order of operations of the DES primitive in 3DES is Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt. It does not specify the amount of key material. That's determined by the key option.

In 3DES, key option 1 uses three independent keys for a total of 168 bits, meaning a brute force attack requires 2^168 attempts. Note that in this case using EDE results in the same amount of work and protection as EEE would.

Key option 2 uses two keys for a total of 112 bits, or 2^112 attempts. They are used in a 1-2-1 pattern, helping protect against a meet-in-the-middle attack.

Key option 3 means the same 56-bit key is used for all three DES operations - the EDE causes the second pass to decrypt the first pass, yielding the plaintext to be reencrypted by the third pass. It's backwards compatible with single DES. This is the reason EDE was created, to serve old 56-bit applications back when they were trying to upgrade from DES.

So that's why EDED doesn't actually make much sense. There is no backwards compatibility it would preserve, so EEEE would be a less complex choice. However, going forward with the idea that 4DES is a decision someone would make over AES-256 (which would probably be a bad idea), I would assume they would do so with four independent keys, for a total strength of 224 bits, or 2^224 attempts.

Note that all these answers are excluding any benefits in performance gained by cryptanalysis of the algorithms.

Comment: In my opinion you should mention the Meet-in-the-middle attack on the first key option. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack

Comment: @Nova I want to know complexity (number of operations)

Comment: @ John Deters
I agree with your answers. 
But can you shed some light at 2^224 attempts when we use 4DES? I dont think we should just add key bits as (56+56+56+56=224) to get complexity.

Comment: @Vinto: Number of operations of the Meet-in-the-middle attack? Just look for it or read the article of my link. (For 4DES it would be at maximum $2^{113}$ operations with needed space of $2^{112} \times 64$ bit.)

Comment: 2^224 is the brute force answer, but as @Nova posted, certain attacks are possible in certain situations. Those attacks reduce the amount of work needed to recover the key. Meet in the middle attacks take advantage of the small key size used by the primitives. But they require massive amounts of space. An attack requiring 2^112x64 bits of space will need 4.1E22 1TB hard drives to execute. As that's not exactly practical today, attackers still need to trade space for rounds of execution.

Comment: @Nova: I dont find any link to your article? Would you do me a favor for that link?

Comment: @Vinto: In my first comment, the wikipedia link. Or search for "meet-in-the-middle attack". (We warned, don't confuse that with the "man-in-the-middle attack".)

Comment: Oops, sorry, my previous comment should be rewritten as "Meet in the middle attacks take advantage of the small *block* size used by the primitives."